# Multiple view on same page with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am testing backbone by making a craft system. You have elements (stone, wood, gold..) and you make items with it.

To make items, you have some recipe, so I have two models:

```
Recipe 
Element
```

At the bottom of my page, I make a list of my elements using a backbone view. It work very well. When you click on an element, I add it to my bag.

My root router :

```
class MyTest.Routers.App extends Backbone.Router
   routes:
    '': 'index'
    'elements/:id' : 'show'

   initialize: ->
     @elements = new MyTest.Collections.Elements()
     @elements.fetch()

   index: ->
      view = new MyTest.Views.ElementsIndex(collection: @elements)
      $('#elements').html(view.render().el)
      @initRecipe()

   initRecipe: ->
     @recipes = new MyTest.Collections.Recipes()
     @recipes.fetch()
     view = new MyTest.Views.RecipesIndex(collection: @recipes)
     $('#recipes').html(view.render().el)

   show: (id) ->
      alert "Element #{id}"
```

My element view :

```
class MyTest.Views.Element extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['elements/element']

  events:
    'element_rended': 'initImagesDatas'
    'click  img' : 'observeImageEvents'
    'click .more': 'addToBag'
    'click .less': 'decreaseNumber'

  tagName : 'li'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(element: @model))
    @currentImage = $(@el).find('img')
    @craftBox = null
    $(@el).trigger('element_rended')
    this

  initImagesDatas: ->
    @currentImage.data('alreadyAdded',false)
    @currentImage.data('position',false)

  observeImageEvents: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $(event.target).parent().next('div.element-description').fadeToggle()

  isAdded: ->
    if (@currentImage.data('alreadyAdded') == true) then true else false

  addToBag: (event) ->
    if (@isAdded())
      @incrementNumber()
    else
      @getNextCraftBox().append(@currentImage.clone())
      @currentImage.data('alreadyAdded',true)
      @incrementNumber()

  getNextCraftBox: ->
    returnItem = $('#craft-area li').eq(0)
    $('#craft-area li').each ->
      if $(this).find('img').length == 0
        returnItem = $(this)
        return false
    @craftBox = returnItem
    return returnItem

  incrementNumber: ->
    @craftBox.find('.number').show()
    @craftBox.find('.number').text(parseInt(@craftBox.find('.number').text())+ 1)

  decreaseNumber: ->
    if parseInt(@craftBox.find('.number').text()) == 1
      @removeToBag()
    else
      @craftBox.find('.number').text(parseInt(@craftBox.find('.number').text())- 1)

  removeToBag: ->
    if (@isAdded())
      @craftBox.parents('ul').append('<li><div class="number">0</div></li>')
      @craftBox.remove()
      @currentImage.data('alreadyAdded',false)
```

My recipe view :

```
class MyTest.Views.Recipe extends Backbone.View

  recipeSelected: null

  template: JST['recipes/recipe']

  tagName : 'li'
  className: 'recipe-li',

  events:
      'click': 'preFillItemsRequired'

  preFillItemsRequired: ->
    if $(@el).hasClass('selected') then $(@el).removeClass('selected') else $(@el).addClass('selected');
    recipeSelected = @model;
    @addIngredient()

  addIngredient: ->
    console.log('pass')

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(recipe: @model))
    this
```

**My question is how can I interact between my two views? How can I get my selected recipe (without using css selector) from my element's view for example?**

My test looks like:

[image: My interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the event triggers

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/30/dont-limit-your-backbone-apps-to-backbone-constructs/

shows the thought at the bottom

or the simpler usage pattern

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette
and look at app.vent: Event Aggregator

Comment: Actually, the more i look at it the better off you might be with just having a selectedRecepie model either from the recipies list or a separate model that both can view

Comment: Thank you, but if i use event triggers, i have to fire it from my recipe model when i selected it, and how can i catch it on my element model?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and the propert MVC way to do it is having them to observe the same model.

A view should not be able to interact with another view, but it should be able to observe a model and change the model state, or change its own state based on the model state.

```
var MyTest.Views.Recipe = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change:selected', this.render, this);
    },
    events: {
        'click': function(){
            this.model.set('selected', this.cid);
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        if( this.model.get('selected') == this.cid ) {
            this.$el.addClass('selected')
        }
        else {
            this.$el.removeClass('selected')
        }
    }
});

var model = new Backbone.Model();

var view1 = new MyTest.Views.Recipe({
    model: model,
});

var view2 = new MyTest.Views.Recipe({
    model: model,
})

// ...
```

Comment: And how can i observe or interact between models?

Comment: Thank you, but i mean... If i want to catch a recipe event from my element model, how can i do that?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: For exemple, when i click on my "recipe" model, i want to execute a function of my "element" model.

Comment: I presume you mean you click on views. when a you click on a view, its internal state can change, and as a result it could: 1. trigger an event and let the app handle it. 2. change a property on a shared model and let other views observe that model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8405/discussion-between-sebastien-and-uzi)