# Trigger click event from one file from another in BackboneJS

Tags: backbone.js

in my project i am not able to trigger click event registered in one backbone view from another backbone view. its actually i am having a file type input placed hidden from the user and i need to trigger the file type input.

```
var FileView = Backbone.View.extend({
 ....
 events : {
  "click .delete-image" : "deleteFile",
 }
 ....
});

var FilesView = Backbone.View.extend({
 ....
 events : {
  "click #attach" : "attachFile",
 },

 attachFile : function() {
  this.fileView.trigger("click .delete-image");
 }
 ....
});
```

but i tried like this the event is not get triggered. how is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `events` hash attaches itself to the jquery element that represents the view, not the backbone view itself. So you would most likely have to do something like this:

```
attachFile : function() {
  $('.delete-image', this.fileView.$el).trigger("click");
}
```

but I would discourage this kind of non-pattern and instead work towards using something we call an Event Aggregation pattern. You can find a collection of really good SO solutions next:

- [fire an event from one view to another in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843278/fire-an-event-from-one-view-to-another-in-backbone)
- [Backbone.js global events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042124/backbone-js-global-events)
- [Multiple view on same page with backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517234/multiple-view-on-same-page-with-backbone-js)